# Which version of Ubuntu should I use to begin my contribution in packaging?

Tags: packaging

I follow the MOTU's [guide about packaging](http://developer.ubuntu.com/packaging/html/getting-set-up.html), there is a note that advice to do the packaging work in the current development version ( I'm running 13.04 ) and to use a VM. I don't know exactly which is the current development version. Should I use 13.04?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Ubuntu NewPackages](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuDevelopment/NewPackages) wiki:

> Submitting new packages through Debian is the preferred path. But, if your package is Ubuntu-specific or can't go into Debian for some other reason, you can submit it directly to MOTU. There are a limited number of available reviewers, so you may encounter delays here.

So, you should consider packaging your software for Debian Sid (the Debian continuous "development" version) and then, once this is accepted, ask for your package to be copied into Ubuntu repositories (this is called syncing, see the [Ubuntu for Debian developers](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubuntu/ForDebianDevelopers#How_can_I_ask_Ubuntu_to_copy_my_package_from_Debian.3F) page).

Practically speaking, and from my own experience, you will have huge difficulties to find a sponsor to review and include your package in Ubuntu directly unless you are really working on some Ubuntu-specific software. It also makes more sense to include your software in Debian as your package will be synced to all other Debian-derived distributions besides Ubuntu. Finding a sponsor in this context will be much easier.

If you want to go through MOTU (upload into Ubuntu directly), [use the current Ubuntu development version here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). At the time this post is written (Tue Apr 30), it is Ubuntu 13.10.

On the opposite, if your goal is not to have a package officially included in the distribution, you may consider using an already released Ubuntu distribution. Usually, in this case, building a Debian package is mainly to avoid configuring and recompiling the same software on a set of computers your own. In this case, just choose the distribution these computers are running as an Ubuntu package for 13.04 will not probably be installable on an older release.

Answer (score 0):

The current development version should, yes, be 13.04, unless there's some daily build of 13.10.

Comment: 13.10 is open for development.  You can develop it in 12.10 or 13.04 and build it for 13.10, but last I checked 13.10 is pretty much identical to 13.04.  But your question is generally wrong, because ***13.04 is a stable release, not a development version of Ubuntu***